# How to crop a text?

Tags: python, string, text

I have a variety of texts and I would like preform an operation that is analogous to cropping a picture.

The document is a few kilobytes in length but the form is

"blah blah title body end blah blah."

What function can I use to do so that `crop(document,"title","end")` and have it return `"title body end"`?

The problem is that functions for replacing text like `string.replace()` always replace some known text with something else. But I know the `title` in each document, the `end` and but the content `before`, between and after is unknown or unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [`find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to get the index of the first occurence of your starting string and [`rfind`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) to get the index of the last occurrence of the ending string. With these to indices you can return the right part of the document with Python's slicing.

```
def crop(doc, start, end):
    return doc[doc.find(start):doc.rfind(end)+len(end)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, for example:

```
import re
doc = "blah blah title body end blah blah."
print re.search('title.+?end', doc).group(0) # title body end
```